# Adding recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to create a simple application which has two activities. Activity A has recyclerview, and Activity B uploads the input data of edittexts. Creating recyclerview and passing data work well, but the view is not created more than 1. I would like to know what did I do wrong.

Activity A which has recyclerview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<MainData> list;
private MainAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    list = (ArrayList<MainData>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");

    adapter = new MainAdapter(list);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Activity B which uploads data.

```
public class upload extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(upload.this, MainActivity.class);

            ArrayList<MainData> list = new ArrayList<>();

            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_name);

            EditText edit_main = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_main);

            list.add(new MainData(edit.getText().toString(), edit_main.getText().toString()));

            intent.putExtra("list",list);

            startActivity(intent);

            finish();

        }
    });
```

Adapter :

```
 public MainAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);

    CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //holder.iv_profile.setImageResource(list.get(position).getIv_profile());
    holder.tv_name.setText(list.get(position).getTv_name());
    holder.tv_content.setText(list.get(position).getTv_content());

    holder.itemView.setTag(position);

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != list ? list.size() : 0);
}

public void remove(int position) {
    try {
        list.remove(position); //
       notifyItemRemoved(position);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected ImageView iv_profile;
    protected TextView tv_name;
    protected TextView tv_content;

    public CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.iv_profile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_profile);
        this.tv_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        this.tv_content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_content);


     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the view is not created more than 1 ?

Comment: @mokhtarhalim only one view is created on the mainactivity. Everytime I try to create second itemview, it does not inflate but just covers the previously created itemview